# Is there anyway to extend more pug files into one pug file?

Tags: javascript, express, backend, pug

Sorry if this has been answered before, haven't been able to find it anywhere but I know in pug it allows you to insert the contents of one Pug file into another. I was wondering if it is possible to insert multiple contents from multiple files into directly one file? I'm having trouble doing so whenever I try to add another line of to my question-display.pug.

```
./questions/question-display.pug
extends ../layout.pug
include ../utils.pug
block content
```

```
/.answers/answer-form
h2 Your Answer
        +errorBlock(errors)
        form(method="post" action="/answers/new")
            input(type="hidden" name="_csrf" value=csrfToken)
            label(for="title") Title
```

I have currently have a pug file to display a question and I want to implement an answer form directly into my question display pug.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking or what issue you're running into. Are you getting an error? If so, what is the error and what is the code that is causing it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is pug mixins.

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER:**

Yes. It is possible to insert multiple contents from multiple files, into another .pug file.

**DESCRIPTION:**

But you need to follow strictly the proper pug indented structure.

In your specific case it should be something similar to this:

```
extends ../layout.pug

block content

    include ../utils.pug
```

As you can see the extends sentence, which basically imports the template, must be located at the top of the .pug view file.

All the subsequents content blocks go behind the extends sentence, but all of them located at the same root level of the indented structure.

Now, whatever you indent behind the content block, all that will be placed where the same block's identifier (must be named 'content' in your case) is located on your layout. That might be directly more pug code, and/or include sentence(s) to other .pug files where the actual code is.

**Note:**
In the layout you should have at least one block to insert additional css code and another one for the actual content on each view that will use such layout.

**Another example:**

**views/home/index.pug**

```
extends ../layouts/main-layout

block styles
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/forms.css")
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/product.css")    

block content
    main(id='main')
        include about
        include facts
```

So, yes. You can import as many files as you want.

**PUG.JS ROCKS**